# Regular Expression get string between char (excluded)

Tags: regex

I need to find a regular expression to match everu char between * delimiter.
I ca have strings like these:

```
*1234-567*
**1234-567**
***1234-567***
*1234-567****
**1234-567****
```

I need to get 1234-567

I did a try with [this one](https://regex101.com/r/BCGrBE/1). The full match of this regex return also the * chars. I do ot need it.

Can you help me?

Comment: What is the language/tool? In PCRE, you might even use such a regex as [`\*\K[^*]+`](https://regex101.com/r/BCGrBE/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What `\K` does exactly?

Comment: @Shafizadeh: It omits the text matched so far. A consuming variant of a positive lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
/\*+([^*]+)\*+/g
```

Noted that `$1` contains what you need.

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SqxRvU/1)

Comment: I actually cannot get the first matching group. I had to find a way to get the values withput matching groups

Comment: @AngeloBadellino I'm not sure I get you right or not, but you can remove everything except needed things like this https://regex101.com/r/SqxRvU/2

Answer (score 0):

if you can utilise lookarounds (generally meaning, it isn't javascript), this will match what you want with no match groups needed:

(lookarounds being "zero-width assertions", they do not actually consume any characters)

```
(?<=\*)[^*\n]+(?=\*)
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/VElGzs/3)